# How to write regular expression that covers small and capital letters of a specific word?

Tags: python, regex, string

I am trying to use regular expression to find a specific word (with small or capital letters) in a text.

Examples are:

- none
- None
- NONE

However, the following code doesn't find the pattern in sample texts.

```
import re

txt_list = ["None" , "none", "[none]", "(NONE", "Hi"]
pattern = "/\bnone\b/i"


for txt in txt_list:
    if re.search(pattern, txt):
        print(f'Found {txt}')
```

What is the cause of the above issue? Is the "pattern" incorrect?

Comment: In python strings, `\b` is the control character "backspace".  It is not "backslash b".

Comment: Make your pattern into a raw string to avoid this behavior. `pattern = r"/\bnone\b/i"`

Comment: Also, why the forward slashes?  This isn't Perl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use slashes to delimit the regular expression. The syntax in Python is different. You can use `(?i)` to ignore case. (Additionally, escape the backslashes or use raw strings.)

```py
pattern = "(?i)\\bnone\\b"
```

You can also pass the `re.IGNORECASE` flag to `re.search`.

```py
pattern = r"\bnone\b"
for txt in txt_list:
    if re.search(pattern, txt, re.IGNORECASE):
        print(f'Found {txt}')
```

Comment: How can I change the above code to identify only text which has 'none' without brackets? I mean only the 1st & 2nd entries of the sample list.

Comment: @Mohammad You can use the start and end anchors: `pattern = r"^none$"`